# Typing the letter "i" into Chrome URL Bar brings up iron-start search, is my browser hijacked?

Tags: google-chrome

**ISSUE:** Whenever I type "i" in lower case it changes the search to iron-start, it doesn't do it with a capital "I". Is this something built into chrome or malware? I have reinstalled Chrome, and reinstalled my OS for other reasons, but once in a while I notice that this still shows up. What is it? How can I remove it? I looked at the website and it doesn't look right. I checked all the extensions as well and don't see anything, and reset chrome to its original settings.

[image: Image of it]

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Or other OS?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Not a duplicate, seems to have been  a unique issue to me, it has been resolved now.

Comment: The site's Q&A format relies on questions being just questions and answers being solutions to them.  Including an answer within the question makes the question unclear, and others can't search for the answer.  Instead, please post the answer as an answer (read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: No one is ever happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** After further investigating, this turned out not to be malware or a browser hijack. In settings of Chrome, under Search, I clicked "Manage Search Engines". In here iron-start.com was listed as a default search engine with the keyword short cut "i". I simply removed this and it no longer pops up in the URL bar when typing "i"

**Reason:** A Couple years ago I installed a program called SRWare Iron, an alternative to chrome, and I believe in doing this, it insert this search engine into my chrome browser. I knew my computer was not infected due to me wiping my computer a couple times due to other reason, as well as reinstalling chrome and reset to default settings. What I found out was that the issue persisted at work and home, where I was both logged into my gmail. It was clear that the default search engines were synchronizing from my gmail account.